# error: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

the problem is clear i just dont know hoe to solve it ...

here is the the entire page :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:provider_practice_part2/controller/user_notifier.dart';
import 'package:provider_practice_part2/models/user.dart';
import 'package:provider_practice_part2/screens/user_list_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider_practice_part2/widgets/cheetah_button.dart';
import 'package:provider_practice_part2/widgets/cheetah_input.dart';
import 'package:provider_practice_part2/widgets/user_list.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeState createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String? _name;
  String? _city;

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UserNotifier userNotifier = Provider.of<UserNotifier>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Consumer(
          builder: (context, title, child) {
            return Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              CheetahInput(
                labelText: 'Name',
                onSaved: (String? value) {
                  _name = value;
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              CheetahInput(
                labelText: 'City',
                onSaved: (String? value) {
                  _city = value;
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  CheetahButton(
                    text: 'Add',
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (!_formKey.currentState!.validate()) return;

                      _formKey.currentState!.save();
                      context
                          .read<UserNotifier>()
                          .addUser(User(_name!, _city!));
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 8),
                  CheetahButton(
                    text: 'List',
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => UserListScreen(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              UserList(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the problem is here :

```
Consumer(
          builder: (context, title, child) {
            return Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            );
          },
        ),
```

as you can see from the title it has an error while I try to pass the data from the consumer to the text widget i have already tried the Null_aware operator and the nullable operator but it doesnt work .....
after all i have solved the problem by deleteting the entire consumer and replacing it with this code :

```
Text(
          context.watch<String>(),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
```

i just want to know if there is any solution to this problem it would be useful for me and other future programmers to see this question .

note : im using provider 5
note : this call is a future to some artificial data just to test how futureprovider work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use

```
Consumer<String>(
...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `Consumer`, you need to pass a generic type parameter to let the class know what it is you are trying to consume, just like what you are doing with `context.watch<String>()`. Because of the way generics work in Dart, if you don't specify a type, Dart will try to use type inference to automatically choose a type. But since there isn't anything to infer from the body of `Consumer`, Dart will just default to the most basic type, which happens to be `Object?`.

This is important not just for letting the code know what type `title` will be, but also because the `Consumer` needs to know what type to look for in all the parent providers it has to sift through to know which one to ultimately listen to.

```dart
Consumer<String>(
  builder: (context, title, child) {
    return Text(
      title,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    );
  },
),
```